# rsync from local folder to mounted nfs share causes permission denied errors and nothing is copied

Tags: permissions, backup, nfs, rsync

I have a home server that is sharing folders on the network using NFS.

I have mounted these folders on my computer, for example:

```
192.168.1.20:/mnt/raiddisk/john  /mnt/john        nfs     auto,defaults   0       0
```

I am trying to run the following rsync command in order to copy my home folder to the remote machine:

```
sudo rsync -azv -h --progress /home/john/ /mnt/john/backups/manual/20150806/ --log-file=/home/john/manual_backup.log
```

But I get errors like this one and nothing is copied over:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/mnt/john/backups/manual/20150806/.":
Permission denied (13) rsync: recv_generator: mkdir
"/mnt/john/backups/manual/20150806/.Skype" failed: Permission denied
(13)
* Skipping any contents from this failed directory *
```

The permissions for my mounted folders are as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Aug  2 21:32 mnt
drwxrwxr-x  4 john  john  4096 Dez 24  2014 john
drwxrwxr-x  4 john  john  4096 Dez 14  2014 backups
drwxrwxr-x 6 john john 4096 Aug  6 20:41 manual
drwxrwxr-x  2 john john 4096 Aug  6 20:41 20150806
```

I thought that by using `sudo` I would be running rsync with root permissions and that it should not have problems copying the files, but evidently there is something I have misunderstood, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the "security" measures in NFS is `rootsquash` being a default option. With `rootsquash`, root on a client system has the same privileges as the `nobody` user (or some other assigned, impotent, account depending on the exact configuration). Accordingly, using `sudo` on NFS actually *weakens* your access privileges. So, don't use `sudo` on NFS. Set your permissions properly.

Comment: Interesting, thanks very much for the info. So I simply omitted "sudo" on the client system and now rsync is happily copying the contents of my /home/john folder to my mounted NFS folders.